# WPF Custom Control Lifecycle Diagram?

Tags: wpf, event-handling, wpf-controls

I am looking for a diagram that will serve as a reference to show the order of events and overrides that get called for WPF custom controls that derive from common classes such as FrameworkElement, UIElement, Control, ContentControl, Decorator, etc.

I am particularly interested in the events and overrides dealing with the process of the control becoming visible and ready to interact with.  In other words, I'm not as interested in this diagram showing the events that could deal with the user interacting with the control after it is ready to be interacted with, such as things like MouseLeftButtonDown.

What I am looking for is something like [**this diagram**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx#Window_Lifetime_Events) (diagrams like these explain the lifecyle of a WPF *window* or *application*) but for custom controls.

I've also seen [**this page**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which, in my opinion makes it seem too simplistic.  That page seems to basically say that there's mostly just the `Initialized`, `Loaded`, and `Unloaded` events.  To illustrate, a few of the *general* events/overrides I've needed to make use of in custom controls include:

- Constructor
- `Loaded`
- `UnLoaded`
- `IsVisibleChanged`
- `OnApplyTemplate`

Along with slightly more specialized overrides like Popup's `OnOpened` and Expander's `OnExpanded`, etc.

The problem I am having is that I *forget when* I can do things like `VisualStateManager.GoToState(...)` (`OnApplyTemplate` is the first real chance I believe).  And I also keep *discovering* events that I need to make use of, such as the IsVisibleChanged (this event proved necessary when I needed a control to do a "reload/refresh" state change when the user returns to the Tab that contains my control).  So I keep wondering are there yet *other* such events/overrides that I should really be paying attention to for a custom control?  **This is where a diagram that shows these things in relation to each other will help.**

Considering these types of events/overrides, [**this Silverlight chart**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2008/10/11/control-lifecycle.aspx) is pretty close to what I'm looking for, **but for WPF**.  Some of the commenters on that post say that WPF's events/overrides are different than Silverlight's.  **If so, can you please point me to a similar diagram?**

To further illustrate the need for such a diagram, consider the following sequence of events that I just witnessed on a custom control that derives from ContentControl:

1. App started up. (My custom control is in a different tab than the intial tab.)
2. `Initialized` event callback called
3. `Loaded` event callback called
4. (I click on the tab that contains my custom control)
5. `IsVisibleChanged` event callback called
6. `OnApplyTemplate` override called
7. `Loaded` event callback called
8. `Loaded` event callback called again
9. `Loaded` event callback called third time in a row
10. (Control is now fully visible and ready to interact with)

Comment: @bitbonk Could be a good idea... I'm not working WPF anymore though so I can't confirm one way or the other.

Comment: @bitbonk Could you post that as an answer to this question (per [this meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262860/3063273))? Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/object-lifetime-events?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 2):

1. Initialised is called only once and first
2. OnApplyTemplate is called second, and whenever the template changes
3. Loaded is called when the control is ready to be displayed and whenever certain containers reload their contents (notably swapping between TabItems)
4. IsVisibleChanged is called whenever the visibility changes, and after loaded

Unloaded is not normally called unless you are in a TabItem and you swap to another one.

The loaded/unloaded events are not called when you would expect unfortunatly, and this makes it tricky to tell when your control should dispose of it's resources. I have also never managed to find a list of the containers that unload and reload their contents.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt such a comprehensive diagram exists. How about you just make it yourself? Override all the methods and/or events your are interested in and put a `Trace.WriteLine(new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);` in each override. Your output will tell you in which order they were called.

Comment: Could be a good idea... I'm not working with WPF anymore though so I can't confirm one way or the other.